# Convertering JavaScript POST request to Google Apps Script code

Tags: google-apps-script

I have tried everything and google wont answer my specific questions so here goes.

I want to convert the following code to Apps Script syntax, the code below works as it is.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('POST', 'https://.......');

request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
request.setRequestHeader('X-Token', 'myTokenHere');

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log('Status:', this.status);
    console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
    console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
  }
};

var body = {
  'fromDate': '2019-01-01T13:54:51+0200',
  'toDate': '2019-05-01T13:54:51+0200'
};

request.send(JSON.stringify(body));
```

What i have tried is for example this:
(all i get is a 500 error)

```
function req(){
  var url = "https://.......";
  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "X-Token": "myTokenHere"
    },
    "payload": {
      "fromDate": "2019-01-01T13:54:51+0200",
      "toDate": "2019-05-01T13:54:51+0200"
    }
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Peace =)

Comment: Payload isn't stringified.

Comment: Alrightm thanks! I will try to solve that, even though im not comletely sure what what means, too me it looks liked it is "stringified" as it is. But i will dig deeper into it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues.

The first, as mentioned in the comments, is that the payload is not a JSON string. Your content type is `application/json` so your payload needs to be formatted to match that mimetype.

Use the [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method (its supported in Apps Script) to achieve that as follows:

```
....
"payload":JSON.Stringify({
    "fromDate": "2019-01-01T13:54:51+0200",
    "toDate": "2019-05-01T13:54:51+0200"
}),
....
```

Your second problem is setting the `contentType` header. It's goes against convention somewhat, but you set the content type as a property on the `options` object (**NOT** the headers object) like so:

```
var options = {
    ...
    "contentType":"application/json",
    "headers":{
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "X-Token": "myTokenHere"
    },
    ...
}
```